# Git: How can I merge changes made between two tags to another branch?

Tags: git, tags, branch, git-branch

I'm trying to manage our Moodle instance on our own branch of the Moodle repo. I checked out tag "v1.9.11" of branch "MOODLE_19_STABLE", then copied that to a new branch "COE", where I've added in our custom theme, etc.

Now that tag "v1.9.12" exists, I want to merge the commits up to that tag into my "COE" branch (and not the commits that came after).

Can I do this with something like [git cherry-pick](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$ git merge v1.9.12
```

will merge all the commits up to, and including, `v1.9.12`, and nothing after that.

Comment: Don't I have to specify the branch that has that tag (MOODLE_19_STABLE), too? Or are tags global to the repo?

Comment: @mrclay: Tags are "global", I guess you could say. In effect, tags and branches are identical -- they're both just names for a particular commit -- but branches are mutable (they point to new commits as new commits are made) whereas tags are immutable.

Comment: To elaborate, tags aren't contained in a branch in the sense that the tag name is only valid within the ancestry of that particular branch, and tags can exist in the ancestry of several branches. They're just a name for a particular commit.

Comment: Implicit part of mipadi's explanation: `git merge` takes a *commit* as an argument. It merges that commit (and by extension all of its ancestry) with your current commit. Tags and branches are two possible ways to specify commits.